# How to create Global Variables in a Unit Test using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have different TestClasses in different .cs file in my visual studio and I want to share some global variable data which is common for every TestMethod in the TestClass.

I would like to know how can I achive this ? 
I am trying to use static or constant variables but where can i declare them when different TestClasses in different .cs files want to use them?

Comment: Depending on what data you need, declaring project settings might also be of use.

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem I created a base class for tests which contained all the common data. This is better from OO point of view.

But you can also declare a public or internal static class with all you constants and data, this is not very elegant but I don't see technical problems with it.